# xamarin - propagate the change of a bindable property to the ios renderer

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.ios-binding

I created a custom control as extension of EntryCell with a bindable property.
I implemented the renderer on ios by extending EntryCellRenderer.
I would like to Change a property of my renderer when the bindable property changes.
EntryCellRenderer has a static Methode OnCellPropertyChanged, which I can't override in my renderer.
Any Idea how could I achieve that?

Best thanks for your Help

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the exact reason for the `OnElementPropertyChanged` method that you can override in the custom renderer.

```
protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
    base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

    if(e.PropertyName == CustomEntryCell.MyCustomThingProperty.PropertyName) { //Make sure to check against your BinableProperty.PropertyName like I am doing here
        //Make your change here
    }
}
```